# Traversing a large array

Tags: java, arrays, large-data

An array has elements(1,2,2,1,1). I have to find the number of distinct elements in the sub array should be equal to the number of distinct elements in the given array i.e the number of **distinct** elements in the array is **2** (1 and 2).

All the possible subarrays are [1,2] , [1,3] , [1,4] , [1,5] , [2,4] , [2,5] , [3,4] , [3,5]

Distinct means no of distinct elements it 2 {1,2,2} has 2 distinct elements.
In this question 1,4 doesn't mean we are including 1st element and 4th element it means our sub array starts from 1 and end at 4 
thus sub array is [1,2,2,1] which has 2 distinct element and it satisfies as the whole array has 2 distinct element.

The problem of the que is that i get test case of **array size** of 2 lacs and i have to get the output in 1 second and each time i get time limit exceed occurs.

After seeing the answer  i have to use buffer reader(instead of scanner {due to performance issue}) and hashmap.

Firstly, i used scanner and buffer reader and both gave output in 2 min 17sec(for 2 lac input). So  why there is need to use buffer reader(using scanner reduced the length of the code).

Secondly,i tested **both the code** on the site and both the code gave output within 1 second whereas in my local machine it took 2 min 17 sec. i didn't understand why there is so much difference.

Third,what is the meaning of this code:
      final int mod = (int)1e9+7;
(though i have seen many times when using large number)

Fourth,What is the use of the below code used with the buffered reader.

I am novice in java so pls give simple answer and sorry for the long post

```
class InputReader
{
private InputStream stream;
private byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
private int curChar;
private int numChars;
private SpaceCharFilter filter;

public InputReader(InputStream stream)
{
    this.stream = stream;
}

public int read()
{
    if (numChars == -1)
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    if (curChar >= numChars)
    {
        curChar = 0;
        try
        {
            numChars = stream.read(buf);
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
        if (numChars <= 0)
            return -1;
    }
    return buf[curChar++];
}

public int readInt()
{
    int c = read();
    while (isSpaceChar(c))
        c = read();
    int sgn = 1;
    if (c == '-')
    {
        sgn = -1;
        c = read();
    }
    int res = 0;
    do
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        res *= 10;
        res += c - '0';
        c = read();
    } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
    return res * sgn;
}

public String readString()
{
    int c = read();
    while (isSpaceChar(c))
        c = read();
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    do
    {
        res.appendCodePoint(c);
        c = read();
    } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
    return res.toString();
}
public double readDouble() {
    int c = read();
    while (isSpaceChar(c))
        c = read();
    int sgn = 1;
    if (c == '-') {
        sgn = -1;
        c = read();
    }
    double res = 0;
    while (!isSpaceChar(c) && c != '.') {
        if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
            return res * Math.pow(10, readInt());
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        res *= 10;
        res += c - '0';
        c = read();
    }
    if (c == '.') {
        c = read();
        double m = 1;
        while (!isSpaceChar(c)) {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
                return res * Math.pow(10, readInt());
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            m /= 10;
            res += (c - '0') * m;
            c = read();
        }
    }
    return res * sgn;
}
public long readLong() {
    int c = read();
    while (isSpaceChar(c))
        c = read();
    int sgn = 1;
    if (c == '-') {
        sgn = -1;
        c = read();
    }
    long res = 0;
    do {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        res *= 10;
        res += c - '0';
        c = read();
    } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
    return res * sgn;
}
public boolean isSpaceChar(int c)
{
    if (filter != null)
        return filter.isSpaceChar(c);
    return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
}

public String next()
{
    return readString();
}

public interface SpaceCharFilter
{
    public boolean isSpaceChar(int ch);
}
}

class OutputWriter
{
private  PrintWriter writer;

public OutputWriter(OutputStream outputStream)
{
    writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new      OutputStreamWriter(outputStream)));
}

public OutputWriter(Writer writer)
{
    this.writer = new PrintWriter(writer);
}

public void print(Object... objects)
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    {
        if (i != 0)
            writer.print(' ');
        writer.print(objects[i]);
    }
 }

public void printLine(Object... objects)
{
    print(objects);
    writer.println();
}

public void close()
{
    writer.close();
}

public void flush()
{
    writer.flush();
}
}
```

Comment: I see way to much code for such a rather small task.

Comment: Using scanner will remove this whole code though i didnt understand the use of the code and also this is my 3rd time seeing this code, thats why i have to post this code and whenever i see this code it is use for  handling large number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your fourth Query : The code is faster than using normal Scanner class.
Hence you can use it in coding competetions.
I made the used the following code on a ~55 MB text file "test.txt".

```
package so;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UseIR {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//checked using the class provided 'InputReader'
InputReader ob=new InputReader(new FileInputStream(new File("src\\so\\test.txt")));
long str=0;
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
long curTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
while((str=ob.read())!=-1){
    sb.append(((char)str));
}
System.out.println("done "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-curTime));

//checked using the Scanner class

curTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("src\\so\\test.txt"));
sb=new StringBuilder();
while(s.hasNext()){
    sb.append(s.next());
}
System.out.println("done "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-curTime));
}
}
```

With the following Output:

```
done 447
done 2061
```

Hope it helps :)